# Native function to scan QR code

Tags: android, google-glass, qr-code, google-gdk

I'm trying to figure out how to scan a QR-code with the google glass.
I was able to dig up some questions about this and they all refered to other libraries and they where quite old(year or even older)

I found that google accepted a [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=344) to make the QR-Code scanner that comes with the google glass available for developers. But since then I can't find any newer info on it.

Is it possible yet to use their QR-Code scanner in our own apps or do we still have to go with third party libraries?

Answer (score 1):

I try'd the same and it seems that this is not possible yet. At the end I used zxing. And since there aren't coming any newer XE versions ... the qr reader is maybe useable with a future glass version.